# Loop through sub -directories, read files starting with given name and append

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a folder with subdirectories which has CSV files. Each subdirectory has CSV files named as modified.csv added_field.csv and retired.csv. How can I loop through each subdirectory read all files in each subdirectory starting with modified, added_field and retired names then recursively append them together?

I have tried **os walk** in this case but I don't have a clue on how I can use **os walk** to read all files in each directory by names, append and move to next directory and perform the same process appending to previous table. Here is my silly code

```
from os import walk
f = []
path ="working dir"
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(path):
     file1 = [filenames for filenames in os.listdir(path) if 
             filenames.startswith("modified")]
    file2 = [filenames for filenames in os.listdir(path) if 
            filenames.startswith("Added_field")]
    file3 = [filenames for filenames in os.listdir(path) if 
            filenames.startswith("Retired")]
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
    df3 = pd.read_csv(file3)
    Finalcombined_df = df1.append([df2,df3], sort=False)
```

My intention is go through each subdirectory read files by just selecting their start names since there are other files there then append them togethe and have a final large table that has combined all tables from each subdirectory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path.cwd()  # if you're in the current working dir
p = Path('to level dir')  # insert a top level path of choice


f_names = ['modified', 'Added_field', 'Retired']

f = [y for x in f_names for y in p.glob(f'**/{x}*.csv') ]  # ** gets all sub-dirs

df =  pd.concat([pd.read_csv(x) for x in f])
```

Comment: why are some columns have a .1 extension. Thought they should match with available columns

Comment: @LivingstoneM You have non-unique column headers in your csv files within one or more files.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all files from all subdirectories using [Path.rglob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob)

```
from pathlib import Path

path = '.'

prefixes = ['modified', 'Added_field', 'Retired']

found = []


for file in Path(path).rglob('*.csv'):
    for p in prefixes:
        if file.name.startswith(p):
            found.append(file)
            break

print(found)
```